# Error: Cannot find module 'koa' - ECS Fargate

Tags: node.js, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a basic node application that I'm building with docker and attempting to utilize with ECS Fargate. When the task is run, however, I see `Cannot find module 'koa'` in the logs, before the container exits in failure.

I imagine this is an ECS-specific problem and am hoping for advice. This is my first time working with ECS and Fargate.

From the local app directory I can successfully run everything using
`npm install` ->
`npm start` .
I can hit a test endpoint that I've configured and get the response that I expect.

On Docker locally, I can run `docker build -t myservice .` and then `docker run -dp 3000:3000 myservice` and I am able to access logs, see that things start as expected and I can hit the same test endpoint with success. The docker container running has a node_modules dir which contains koa

Are there environment specific things I should be configuring for this to work with ECS & Fargate?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:7.10.1

WORKDIR /srv
ADD . .
RUN npm install --production --silent
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

Comment: It really sounds like you aren't actually running the same image locally as you are on ECS. There is nothing specific about ECS that would cause your docker image to work differently in this way.

Comment: Thanks @MarkB - it seemed really weird to me that perhaps I had to set some kind of additional config for the ecs environment or something (makes no sense) so it must be me and docker. I’ll investigate more